# Using NSOperation I want to add a subview to my current UIViewController, not sure how to access this from inside an operation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nsoperation

I have a `NSOperation` that gets an array of message objects and cycles through them. For each message object I want to add a `UIView` to the current `UIViewController`. Only problem is I can't access the view from the `NSOperation`. Is there any way around this?

Thanks

code below (my main method in the NSOperation):

```
- (void)main {

    //main code here

    NSLog(@"Display messages");

    //First match the user with the messageBank
    PFQuery *messageBankQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"messageBank"];
    [messageBankQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [messageBankQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if(!error) {

            //first object matches
            PFObject *messageBank = objects[0];
            PFRelation *receivedMessages = [messageBank relationForKey:@"receivedMessages”];
            PFQuery *receivedMessagesQuery = [receivedMessages query];
            [receivedMessagesQuery orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];

            [receivedMessagesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                if((!error) &&([objects count]>0)) {

                    for(PFObject *message in objects) {



                        UIView *content = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"messageView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];


                        //this doesn't have a view to add to!!!

                    }

                    [self completeOperation];
                }//end if

                else {

                    [self completeOperation];                 }

            }];

        }


    }];    



}
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: sorry, just edited now